# How to remove all element from array except the first one in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, array-splice

I want to remove all element from array except the element of array at 0th index

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Output should be `a`

Comment: `var output = Input[0];`

Comment: Or `Input.slice().splice(1)` if you actually want an array. And if you don’t care about the original array, use `Input.splice(1)`.

Comment: okay my requirement is like that i have to implement a functionality called remove tab which remove all the tab from tabset array except the home tab which is the tab at 0th index.

Comment: Are these "tabs" actually some HTML elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: i don't know but splice(0,1) is not working for me it remove home tab(tab at 0th index) from tabset which is not desirable.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can set the `length` property of the array.

```js
var input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];  
input.length = 1;
console.log(input);
```

OR, Use [`splice(startIndex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method

```js
var input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];  
input.splice(1);
console.log(input);
```

OR use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method

```js
var input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];  
var output = input.slice(0, 1) // 0-startIndex, 1 - endIndex
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I've been surprised by `input.length = 1` solution. I thought that `length` is read-only property :)

Comment: What are advantages/disadvantages of each approach? I was also surprised by array.length=1

Comment: how to use by value

Answer (score 5):

This is the `head` function. `tail` is also demonstrated as a complimentary function.

Note, you should only use `head` and `tail` on arrays that have a known length of **1** or more.

```js
// head :: [a] -> a
const head = ([x,...xs]) => x;

// tail :: [a] -> [a]
const tail = ([x,...xs]) => xs;

let input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

console.log(head(input)); // => 'a'
console.log(tail(input)); // => ['b','c','d','e','f']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use splice to achieve this.

```
Input.splice(0, 1);
```

More details here . . .http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
remaining = array[0];
array = [remaining];
```

Comment: Or just `array = [array[0]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice:

```js
var input =['a','b','c','d','e','f'];  
input = input.slice(0,1);
console.log(input);
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it in an `array`, you can use `slice` or `splice`. Or wrap the wirst entry again.

```js
var Input = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];  

console.log( [Input[0]] );
console.log( Input.slice(0, 1) );
console.log( Input.splice(0, 1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

[input[0]];

// ["a"]
```

Comment: Hey, you should explain your answer a bit. What were your thoughts behind it? As well may firstly fully write our answer before posting it ;)

Comment: @WolverinDEV Could you explain the downvote? I came across this post and read that two of the top solutions used splice & slice. I provided a solution with the least amount of characters required...

Answer (score 0):

The `shift()` method is a perfect choice to do this.

```
var input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];  
let firstValue = input.shift();
console.log(firstValue);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var output=Input[0]
```

It prints the first element in case of you want to filter under some constrains

```
var Input = [ a, b, c, d, e, a, c, b, e ];
$( "div" ).text( Input.join( ", " ) );

Input = jQuery.grep(Input, function( n, i ) {
  return ( n !== c );
});
```